# Zero Opengl 3.2 pixelformat matches found?

Tags: windows, opengl, match, zero, pixelformat

Today I finally found out what has been stalling my development process: Even though no errorcode is set, the function wglChoosePixelFormatARB returns 0 pixelformats.
I am trying to set up an OpenGL context in my C++ application and I have managed to retrieve the function pointers for the extensions.

`glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &maj)`

returns 4 so, naturally, I assumed it would be possible to create an OpenGL 3.2 context. However, after finding out there were no matches, I started to comment out some of my requirements to go in the attribList parameter. There were no matches whatsoever.
Only when I, just to be certain, commented out

`WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3, 
WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,`

I finally got matches. Out of the 8 matching pixel formats that the other requirements meet, not ONE of them seems to support version 3 of OGL.

Has anyone ever run into this? I have tried updating/reinstalling my video drivers, but nothing has changed. I am running this on Windows 7, MS Visual Studio 2008, and my graphics card is one from the AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB`, `WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB` and related attributes are **not** attributes of the Windows Pixelformat. 
You must not use them with `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()`.

Those options belong into the attribute list of `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` as defined by the [`WGL_ARB_create_context`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt) extension.

Comment: Thanks! I should have known, I was looking at two different documentations at the same time >.< I started with wglCreateContextAttribsARB but it seems I didn't first assign a traditional pixelformat to the newly created rendering context. Thanks for the help! Kudos!